# setcookie to an empty value not working

Tags: php, cookies

i have this code im trying to do for a type of cache system so it remembers the city the user has selected. if the user has selected a city it stores it in sessions and cookies, and will automatically redirect them to the city page if they've selected it before.

sessions work fine, but it doesn't seem to be setting the cookie to an empty value if the $_GET['city'] variable is empty...

heres my code:

```
function gen_url ($city)
{
    $url = 'http://www.mysite.com';

    if (!empty($city)) $url .= "/c-$city";

    return $url;
}

function set_cache ($variable, $value)
{
    $_SESSION[$variable] = $value;
    setcookie($variable, $value, time() + 31536000);
}

$redirect = false;
$redirect_array['city'] = '';

if (!empty($_GET['city']))
{
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from `cities` where `slug`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['city'])."'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            foreach ($row as $k => $v)
                $city[$k] = $v;
        }

        $redirect_array['city'] = $city['slug'];
    }
    else
    {
        $redirect = true;
    }
}   

if ($redirect)
{
    header('Location: '.gen_url($redirect_array['city']);
    die();
}

set_cache('city', $redirect_array['city']);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't set a cookie with an empty string as it will delete the cookie.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all other
>   arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie with the
>   specified name will be deleted from the remote client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not correct in *every* version of PHP (see 5.6.10) as I found and reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37464332/469643. In some versions, setting a blank value **will succeed** and the documentation does not make it clear what *should* happen if **no previous call** has been made. My question still needs an answer if you have any deeper insights

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a cookie to most falsy values to indicate falseness of a trit cookie.  Only `'0'` will work.  Use that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cookie to an empty value by using a null byte as the value, like this:

```
setrawcookie('testEmptyCookie', "\x00", time() + 3600, '/');
```

(tried on php 5.6 and 7.2).

Answer (score 2):

PHP's setcookie() doesn't allow you to set cookies with empty values. But you can do that with header()

replace:

```
setcookie($variable, $value, time() + 31536000);
```

with:

```
header('set-cookie: '.rawurlencode($variable).'='.rawurlencode($value).'; max-age=31536000', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set your cookie with a negative time:

```
setcookie($variable, '', -1);
```