# Does PHP's setcookie() sometimes require a value?

Tags: php, cookies

I have been using the following code for a while to detect whether or not cookies are enabled but it was just recently discovered that even with browsers set to allow for cookies it wasn't succeeding. It is a simple check on whether or not to rely on cookies in the processing.

We recently migrated to PHP version 5.6.21 but the [current `setCookie()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) doesn't say anything about changing the setcookie approach but makes it clear that if you don't specify anything a blank value is the default. We also get different behavior with PHP version 5.6.10.

Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8775572/469643) speaking to this similar issue but does not mention the PHP version being used.

To the documentation's credit, all the examples of setting cookies passes a value (except the deletion part) and here is a note about passing blank:

> If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all other arguments **match a previous call to setcookie**, then the cookie with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client [emphasis mine]

My interpretation of that is that if the cookie does **not** exist (no prior call to setcookie with that name) **it should create it**.

The code:

```
# Before any html is output:
function cookiesEnabled(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE["cookiesEnabled"])){
        return true;
    }else{
        if(isset($_GET["reloaded"])){
            return false;
        }else{
            setcookie("cookiesEnabled" /*,"ANY_VALUE_FIXES"*/);
            $query = "";
            if($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]){
                $query = "&".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
            }
            header("Location: ?reloaded=1".$query);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
# Check prior to any HTML content being echoed
if(!cookiesEnabled()){
    echo "Problem";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

"Success" only appears when a `value` parameter is given.

I am content populating a value as a "fix" / "workaround" and I'm glad it seems to work (and is easy) but this question is posed to **learn about why the behavior seems to differ from the documentation and hopefully to gain confirmation** from someone else.

Our PHP version requiring a value is 5.6.21. I'm not sure what other server settings could be causing this behavior. In a different server with PHP 5.6.10, the value parameter **is not required** for "Success". When we just upgraded its version to 5.6.21, it also failed.

Does PHP need to update their documentation to explicitly state a value is required or was a coding bug introduced? I don't have any contacts to address either so thanks for forwarding this potential discrepancy to the powers that be.

Note: If I `setcookie` like this `setcookie("cookiesEnabled", "")`, the result is the same as not passing it (Success in 5.6.10, not in 5.6.21) so at least the documentation probably *is* defaulting it to "".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8775627/4007002 Empty cookies are automatically deleted, it's in the docs btw.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't find that question but it is quite similar. Too bad he didn't mention the PHP version since my two versions are behaving very differently. I acknowledged that same line of documentation in my question but if the cookie's name had **not** been previously seen, that seems to imply that creation would take place -- although not explicitly told

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll chalk it up to version differences and a behind-the-scenes coding change that I landed on accidentally. It still isn't clear, though, which way is correct based on PHP's documentation.

I believe the PHP 5.6.21 version to represent an introduced bug and creating a cookie without a value (where there was none present before) should still be possible. If the new behavior is permanent, the documentation definitely needs to be updated.

As far as I know, prior to and including PHP 5.6.10 it was not required to pass a value to create *a new* cookie.

If someone more intimate with PHP's inner workings can speak to the intention of `setcookie()` without passing a value (and no prior existence with that name) that would be great.

Since the documentation didn't change between these two versions, one of the approaches is wrong and I'm hoping this question can get the ball rolling towards a fix.

If you have encountered this problem as well, thanks for chiming in by commenting.