# Why PHP Cookie variable is not saved after closing Chrome

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

i'm learning to use cookies in PHP. I was expecting that every time i set a cookie, the cookie and all of his variables are stored on the client site so i could use them again next time the user will visit the site. Anyway in the next example (a web application with a sign in option, i use cookies to store a unique string so i could implement "Remember me" option) i can access the id of the stored cookie but the variables data seem lost. Here is example of the code i use and screenshots of what i get.

## Setting up a Cookie

```
 if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
    $token=uniqid($_SESSION['id']);
    $sql="UPDATE users SET token='$token' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
    $conn->query($sql);   
    setcookie("remember_me", $token, time()+30*24*60*60*1000);
}
else{
    setcookie("remember_me","",time()-1000);
}
```

### User page

On the user page it just simply prints out the $_COOKIE and $_SESSION array.

```
<?php 
    echo "SESSION: ";
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<br>
<?php
    echo "COOKIE: ";
    print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

### Process:

- First i delete all the cookies using the advice i found here: 
  [how to delete all cookies of my website in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php)
- Then log inside
   [Log in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUuOm.png)
   (this form call a script that execute the code for setting a cookie i gave at the beginning, then redirect to the user-page) 
  [User page before closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns887.png)
- Close the browser and open it again directly at the user-page (without executing other scripts 
   /localhost/MIAFormApp/script/db/HTML_PROBA/user-page.html.php  
   [User page after re-opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7yvr.png)

What did i get wrong and why the cookies array after re-opening is empty?

## EDIT:

The second time i open browser the script for seting the cookie is not executed. I just set the url to go to the user-page.php . 

 Examp:
/localhost/MIAFormApp/script/db/HTML_PROBA/user-page.html.php

Comment: I think this is problem `if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {` When it is false, it's expiring cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the else statement in your sample code - meaning go from:

**This**

```
if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
    $token=uniqid($_SESSION['id']);
    $sql="UPDATE users SET token='$token' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
    $conn->query($sql);   
    setcookie("remember_me", $token, time()+30*24*60*60*1000);
}
else{
    setcookie("remember_me","",time()-1000);
}
```

**To this**

```
if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
    $token=uniqid($_SESSION['id']);
    $sql="UPDATE users SET token='$token' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
    $conn->query($sql);   
    setcookie("remember_me", $token, time()+30*24*60*60*1000);
}
```

When you re-open your browser, the if statement is going to check whether or not the POST variable *remember_me* was found. The only time that it will be found is when someone logs in because the login form is sending that information on form submit. In every other instance ( such as re-opening the browser), the else statement will be executed which isn't what you want. The reason being that setting an empty value on a cookie will [delete said cookie.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775627/6294061)

Comment: Well actually the second time i open the browser i don't execute that script. i set the url to show directly to the user-page

Comment: @NVelichkovski Ah! Gotcha. Have you tried checking whether your browser is configured to delete cookie data on browser close? ( This is an option on all major browsers as far as I know ). I tested your sample code and I'm able to see the cookie when I re-open the browser, which then suggests that the issue might not be related to your code.